# Memory leak when setting attributedText on 2 labels in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, memory-leaks, uilabel, nsattributedstring

I'm seeing a strange memory leak reported by instruments when I set the attributedText parameter on 2 labels in a view.

If I only set the attributed text on one label, I dont get the memory leak.
Also, this only seems to leak if the labels are multi-line labels.

To replicate this, I put 2 labels on a storyboard view controller, connected the IBOutlets, and used the following code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController
{
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var label2: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        paragraphStyle.alignment = .Natural
        paragraphStyle.lineHeightMultiple = 1.0
        paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = .ByWordWrapping

        let attributes = [
            NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 15.0)!,
            NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.blackColor(),
            NSKernAttributeName: 0.4,
            NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle,
            NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: NSUnderlineStyle.StyleNone.rawValue
        ]

        self.label.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.", attributes: attributes)
        self.label2.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.", attributes: attributes)
    }
}
```

A screenshot of the leaks reported by instruments:
[image: Instruments reported leaks]

Here's a link to the [sample project][2].

Any ideas what could be the issue?

Comment: Found out why in the end?